# Some Dense subset of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with its usual topology?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

1. The set of all invertible matrices i.e $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$
2. The set of all matrcies having both real eigen values.
3. Having $Trace(A)=0$

$3$ is not dense set as It is closed set!

$1$ Is dense. take any $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, suppose $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigen values of $A$, chhose $\lambda<\min\{|\lambda_1,|\lambda_2|\}$

Now consider the sequence $A_n= A+{\lambda\over n}I\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and clearly $A_n\rightarrow A$

I have no Idea how to conclude $2$. Thanks for helping and correcting me.

Comment: If one eigenvalue is positive and one is negative, then the determinant is negative and that remaing true after a small perturbation.

Comment: @PeterFranek what if one is $0$ and another is non zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if a certain expression involving the trace and determinant is negative, the eigenvalues are non-real.

Comment: $(Tr(A))^2-4\det (A)\ge 0$ inorder to become real eigen values. $(Tr(A))^2-4\det (A)= 0 \implies (a_{11}+a_{22})^2-a_{11}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}= 0.$ $(a_{11}+a_{22})^2-a_{11}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}= 0.$ will be a surface. $(a_{11}+a_{22})^2-a_{11}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}\ge 0$ will be region above that surface. which is never dense.

Comment: Is my arguments correct?

Comment: The point is simply that the set where the discriminant is negative is open and nonempty.